# Regex from .NET to Java

Tags: java

I have a function in .NET that verifies that all characters in a string are just ABC. If the string contains anything other than ABC it returns false

Return true example:   "ABAABCCCABAB"

Return false example:  "AAGSRJJ #% # ° AQYJ"

I need to pass that to Java and I have no idea how to do it.
Can somebody help me?

```
for (int i = 0; i < ADN.dna.Length; i++)  //recorrer las filas
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(ADN.dna[i], @"[^ABC]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) == true)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `[ABC]{1,20}` where 20 is max length - but you may have to invert your return to true

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `java.util.regex.Pattern` class.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[ABC]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
for (int i = 0; i < ADN.dna.length; i++) {
    if (!pattern.matcher(ADN.dna[i]).matches()) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Regex pattern `[ABC]+` explanation:

The input must be one or more (indicated by +) of charcters in the set `ABC`.

And here's your test cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[ABC]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  System.out.println(pattern.matcher("ABAABCCCABAB").matches());
  System.out.println(pattern.matcher("AAGSRJJ #% # ° AQYJ").matches());
}
```

Result:

```
true
false
```

Comment: @Arvind The edited answer is a mistake lol. It's going to exit immediately on the first item if you remove the if block.

Comment: I had corrected two things: (1) From `Length` to `length` (2) Multiline to a single line. I agree with what you say. However, when I gave a second look into the question, I think you should one of the two things: change `[ABC]+` to `[^ABC]+` or change the condition to `if (!pattern.matcher(ADN.dna[i]).matches()) {
        return false;
    }`

Comment: The regex `[^ABC]+` doesn't work as you expect it to. What do you think `^` even adds to the regex? I've negated the if condition after I reread the question.